# Android listSelector being applied to whole view rather than items

Tags: android, listview

I have this code for a `ListView`:

```
<ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/searchButton"
            android:divider="@color/DarkGoldenrod"
            android:dividerHeight="0.1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />
```

And this is the code for the drawable - `list_selector`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime">

   <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_green_dark" android:state_pressed="true"/>
   <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_blue_light" android:state_selected="true"/>
   <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_orange_light" android:state_activated="true"/>

</selector>
```

This selector is being applied to the whole listview, how do i apply it to the individual list items?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List selector is applied for the whole `listview` for this if you are inflating a view for listview row then apply that style for that total view layout.otherwise in your onListitemClick method it will give us a view apply your drawable there to the view by `view.setBackgroundResource(resid)`

Answer (score 0):

use listSelector instead of background

```
 <ListView
  android:id="@android:id/list"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_below="@+id/searchButton"
  android:divider="@color/DarkGoldenrod"
  android:dividerHeight="0.1dp"
  android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
  android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should check type of element when you click on it. And change background this item in adapter.

Answer (score 0):

A listview selector will be applied to the whole view since it gets the focus.. In order to apply it to just a portion of the view, then in that case, apply the drawable on the view inside the layout used to inflate the listview.

That is:
Say you have a relative layout, and a textview inside, then set the drawable to the textview and set "setFocusable" true and setfocusableon touch true for the textview.

try this.